# Although there are many kinda like me, it all started with me

Tags: riddle, knowledge

*At the bottom I'm **never** happy or unhappy.
 To the left of the bottom I'm **always** happy. 
 To the right of the bottom I'm **always** happy.

 At the bottom my ' is **never** happy or unhappy.
 To the left of the bottom my ' is **always** unhappy.
 To the right of the bottom my ' is **always** happy.

Overall, at least I **look** happy.*

**Who Am I?**

Comment: Your *what*?  Apostrophe (or something shaped like one)?

Comment: @dan04 It's part of the riddle. You have to figure out what that means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> The function $f(x) = x^2$, or something similar

At the bottom I'm never happy or unhappy.

> The bottom here refers to $x=0$ where the graph takes its minimum. At this point $f(x)=0$ which is neither **positive** nor **negative** (synonymous with happy/unhappy)

To the left of the bottom I'm always happy.

> For $x<0$, $f(x)$ is always **positive**.

To the right of the bottom I'm always happy.

> For $x>0$, $f(x)$ is always **positive**.

At the bottom my ' is never happy or unhappy.

> ' here refers to the first derivative which in this case is the function $g(x) = 2x$. I take the bottom here to still refer to the bottom of $f(x)$ and at $x=0$, $g(x) = 0$ which is neither **positive** nor **negative**.

To the left of the bottom my ' is always unhappy.

> For $x<0$, $g(x)$ is always **negative**

To the right of the bottom my ' is always happy.

> For $x>0$, $g(x)$ is always **positive**

Overall, at least I look happy.

> The graph of $f(x) = x^2$ looks like a big smile.

Comment: Great job! This is exactly the answer I had in mind. Although other rot13(tencuf) can fit, I tried to rule them out with the help of the title.